# Moving SVG object on guideline using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to move SVG object on `<path>` guideline I created, my code is based on this [one](https://codepen.io/maellegomezafpa/pen/mxEgmq), but I can't figure out why mine doesn't work and the codepen I shared does.

```js
function positionTheElement() {
 var html = document.documentElement;
 var body = document.body;
 var scrollPercentage = (html.scrollTop + body.scrollTop) / (html.scrollHeight - html.clientHeight);
 var path = document.getElementById("trace");
 var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
 var pt = path.getPointAtLength(scrollPercentage * pathLen );
 var element = document.getElementById("etoile");
 element.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+ pt.x  + "," + pt.y + ")");
};
window.addEventListener("scroll", positionTheElement);
positionTheElement();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1920 4000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 4000;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path class="st12" id="trace" d="M1491.8,3999l-7.8-365c0,0-1156-14-1240.5-1.3S155,3552,155,3552s3-594-0.3-688.1
  c-3.3-94.1,94.3-81.9,94.3-81.9l689,5c0,0,645,5,751.9,6s90.1-93,90.1-93s20-468,14-576s-96.2-89.6-96.2-89.6S288,2039,208,2034.4
  S120,1931,120,1931s13-1156,6-1184s4-60,10-89c0-33,141-28,141-28s764-1,867,0s154-11,169-19c36.8-10.9,26.8-27.7,28-53l2.5-525.5"
  stroke="tomato" fill="none" stroke-width="4"/>
    <polygon class="st11" id="etoile" stroke="tomato" fill="none" stroke-width="4" points="1367.7,59.8 1345.4,49.8 1324.5,62.3 1327.3,38.3 1308.8,22.4 1332.8,17.6 1342.3,-4.7 1354.3,16.3 
  1378.7,18.4 1362.2,36.2 "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

How can I animate the SVG polygon on the path guideline correctly?

Comment: Something to note: your star has it's origin at the start of the line you'd like to move it along. The star in your example has the origin at roughly 0,0 - that is to say, by translating, you need to end up on the line. If you start on the line, you're going to be translated further than you'd like and in your case, though I haven't worked it out, probably off screen. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

1. the star should have the center in the origin of the svg canvas (x=0; y=0).
2. the path `trace` has to be reversed. The way it's drawn (from the bottom up) would make the star begin it's movement from the bottom of the document to the top.

```js
function positionTheElement() {
 var html = document.documentElement;
  
 var body = document.body;
 var scrollPercentage = (html.scrollTop + body.scrollTop) / (html.scrollHeight - html.clientHeight);
 var path = document.getElementById("trace");
 var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
 var pt = path.getPointAtLength(scrollPercentage * pathLen );
 var element = document.getElementById("etoile");
 element.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+ pt.x  + "," + pt.y + ")");
};
window.addEventListener("scroll", positionTheElement);
positionTheElement();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1920 4000" >
<g>
 <path class="st12" id="trace" d="M1343.5,32.5
           L1341,558C1339.8,583.3 1349.8,600.1 1313,611C1298,619 1247,631 1144,630C1041,629 277,630 277,630C277,630 136,625 136,658C130,687 119,719 126,747C133,775 120,1931 120,1931C120,1931 128,2029.8000000000002 208,2034.4C288,2039 1697.8,2034.4 1697.8,2034.4C1697.8,2034.4 1788,2016 1794,2124C1800,2232 1780,2700 1780,2700C1780,2700 1796.8000000000002,2794 1689.9,2793C1583,2792 938,2787 938,2787L249,2782C249,2782 151.39999999999998,2769.8 154.7,2863.9C158,2958 155,3552 155,3552C155,3552 159,3645.3999999999996 243.5,3632.7C328,3620 1484,3634 1484,3634L1491.8,3999"
  stroke="tomato" fill="none" stroke-width="4"/>
    <path class="st11" id="etoile" stroke="tomato" fill="none" stroke-width="4" d="M25,33.5l-22.3,-10l-20.9,12.5l2.8,-24l-18.5,-15.9l24,-4.8l9.5,-22.3l12,21l24.4,2.1l-16.5,17.8z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you that works but on my full SVG it applies differently, the star skips the guidelines on scroll, what can cause this?

Comment: Without seeing what you have I can't tell you anything

Comment: I had box-sizing on all elements, this for some reason caused the jumps. thank you again.

Comment: How did you reversed the trace path though?

Comment: First I change all the commands to absolute (uppercase) and then I begin the reversed path where your path ends reversing all the commands one by one and ending the path where your path begin

Comment: Do you mind take a look on this? https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/OJyEGOa . for some reason the tracking guideline moved to the right, all I changed is the polygon with group of paths. search for wipe in the html section to find the relevant code

Comment: As I've commented in my answer *the star should have the center in the origin of the svg canvas (x=0; y=0).* In your code the `wipe` is the equivalent of the star. It's center is not in 0.

Comment: So how can I tell his x and y? and can you redirect me to place I can read more about it? I'm completely new to this.

Comment: you can do this in Javascript: `console.log(wipe.getBBox())` This is returning the bounding box of the wipe: an object with a x, y,width, height. the center of the wipe is at x+width/2, y+height/2